# Variable resistor in LTSPICE

Tags: resistance, ltspice

I have a requirement to vary resistance according to time in finite number of steps. I have already come across a solution where we can time vary resistance value by creating a time varying voltage source with name say Vr and then assigning R = V(Vr) for resistance value but I want to achieve this using finite many values, i.e. Resistance is supposed to take only a number of values which will be varying with time and is periodic.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: So, it boils down to creating a voltage source with step increments maybe?

Comment: For simulation purpose, Yes! A periodic triangular profile with step increments is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Andy mentions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559553/variable-resistor-in-ltspice#comment1459360_559553), you just need to make your controlling source with a quantized voltage. The simplest way would be using a behavioural voltage with:

```
V = int(time*N)/N
```

Where `time` can also be any other time-dependent waveform you have (e.g. `V(x)`). As it is it ensures that there are `1/N` Volts/step.

There are two main "caveat emptor":

1. The more steps you'll need, the less resolution you'll have. For this, the behavioural sources have two parameters, `tripdv` (Volts) and `tripdt` (seconds). For rates of change that happen within `tripdv/tripdt` [V/s], the timestep is forced to a reduced form, trying to preserve the waveform. For values beyond, the timestep is not forced in any way and it may or may not "fly-by" (but most likely the former). These are preferred over imposing tighter timesteps, since the latter will force the simulation to crawl for all the duration, whereas the two parameters will only force it when needed. Adding `.opt plotwinsize=0` will certainly help.
2. The usage of `int()` or its cousins, `floor()`, `ceil()`, or `round()` (but also `if()` & co), will introduce discontinuities and these are the enemies of SPICE solvers. This means that your variable resistor will inherit these discontinuities which, depending on what simulation you have, may, or may not cause hiccups. Word of caution.

Other ways include creating your own circuit, maybe with the `[SpecialFunctions]/sample`, or with the A-devices, or simply various levels of voltage with VCSW. Not all will be as efficient, and not all will be simulation-time-friendly (some may turn out to be CPU hogs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for my simulation.

Answer (score 0):

A *multiplying DAC*does exactly that. There's quite a few of these, and their manufacturers offer SPICE models for them, which you can use to model your own.

Other than that, the  classical R-2R ladder DAC is an excellent way to build a "reconfigurable resistor", and it just takes a few voltage-controlled switches, these resistors and an appropriate voltage ramp to implement a sequence of resistance values.